# Firebase pushing array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase to store information for a workout application.

I user adds a workout name and then I push it to the database. I can continue pushing these but my issue is that it does not seem to be pushing as an array just an object. See the screen shots below...

[image: Console log from firebase object]

[image]

As you can see in the console log picture the workouts property is an object not an array like I expect.

The code I'm using to push it:

```
    let newWorkout = {
      title: 'title',
      exercises: [{
        name: 'pulldownsnsn',
        sets: 4
      }]}

    let ref = firebase.database().ref("/userProfile/"+this.userId);

    ref.child("workouts").push(newWorkout);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Firebase Database stores lists of data in a different format, to cater for the multi-user and offline aspects of modern web. The `-K...` are called push IDs and are the expected behavior when you call `push()` on a database reference.

See this [blog post on how Firebase handles arrays](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html), this blog post on the format of those keys, and the [Firebase documentation on adding data to lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data).

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are handy, but they are a distributed database nightmare for one simple reason: index element identification is not reliable when elements get pushed or deleted. Firebase database instead uses keys for element identification:

```
// javascript object
['hello', 'world']

// database object
{ -PKQdFz22Yu: 'hello', -VxzzHd1Umr: 'world' }
```

It gets tricky when using `push()`, because it does not actually behaves like a normal push, but rather as a key generation followed by object modification.

Example usage

```
firebase.database().ref('/uri/to/list').push(
    newElement,
    err => console.log(err ? 'error while pushing' : 'successful push')
)
```

Comment: Did you figure it out? Any suggestion? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example from firebase documentation:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
// ...
const washingtonRef = db.collection('cities').doc('DC');

// Atomically add a new region to the "regions" array field.
const unionRes = await washingtonRef.update({
  regions: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion('greater_virginia')
});
// Atomically remove a region from the "regions" array field.
const removeRes = await washingtonRef.update({
  regions: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove('east_coast')
});
```

More info on [this firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

Comment: Your answer is based on Cloud Firestore, and the question is reference to Firebase Real Time Database. So this code won't work in RTDB.